# Slideshow resizing for media queries

Tags: css, media-queries, media

i have a slideshow built on my landing page but, what i am wanting to do is have that slideshow scale down and scale in relation to the page. i have managed to do this with all other divs/content it is just this pesky slideshow that's not doing as it is told. It is probably something very simple but i have been staring at this site a bit TOO much now.

css:

```
    .slideshow { 
        margin: 0px 5px 5px 5px; 
        position: relative; 
        width: 920px; 
        height: 610px;
```

}

```
#slide2, #slide3, #slide4, #slide5, #slide6, #slide7, #slide8 { 
        position: absolute;
        width: 520px;
        height: 156px;
        padding: 227px 200px 227px 200px;
        text-align: center;
        color: #FFF;
```

}

```
#slide1 { 
        position: absolute;
        width: 520px;
        height: 20px;
        padding: 295px 200px 295px 200px;
        text-align: center;
        color: #FFF;
```

}

Snippet of HTML:

```
<!--Slideshow-->        
  <div class="slideshow">

       <!--We design and communicate-->

        <div id="slide1">
            <span style="line-height: 120%; color: #FFF; font-size: 20px; font-weight: normal;">
            We are a design and communication agency.
            </span>
        </div>

       <div id="slide3"><a href="about/how-we-work.htm">    
            <span style="line-height: 120%; color: #FFF; font-size: 20px; font-weight: normal;">
            We create.
            <br>
            <br>
            branding / web design / packaging / events / press launches / interiors / installations
            <br>
            <br>
            <span style="border-bottom: solid 3px #FFF;">
            our process
            </span>
            </span>
       </a></div>

        <!--Bloom and Blossom-->
       <div id="slide2"></div>

       <!--Elkin-->
       <div id="slide4"></div>

       <!--GKFW-->
       <div id="slide6"></div>

       <!--Swarovski-->
       <div id="slide7"></div>

       <!--ASOS-->
       <div id="slide8"></div>

    </div>
```

my aim is to have this taking up 100% width like all the other divs.

Thanks if anyone can help and apologies in advance for some appalling coding! hah u__u been out the game too long.

this is the MQ stylesheet that i have:

```
.slideshow { 
        margin: 0 5px 5px 5px; 
        position: relative; 
        width:98%; 
        }


#slide2, #slide3, #slide4, #slide6, #slide7, #slide8 { 
        position: absolute;
        width: 98%;
        margin: 0px 5px 5px 0;
        text-align: center;
        color: #FFF;
                    }

#slide1 { 
        position: absolute;
        width: 98%;
        height: 20px;
        margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
        text-align: center;
        color: #FFF;
                    }
```

there is also a wrapper which is 100% width

Answer (score 0):

You fixed heights and widths in pixels. Change them to percentages.
Pixels doesn't scale down. A pixel is a pixel and percentage is the relative one.
So fix heights and widths in percentages

Comment: sorry, i should have said that this was my normal stylesheet i am using. i have coded a media-queries stylesheet using percentages and that's what i am scratching my head at.